# in testng.xml run as testng suit triggers IE browser & run each test manually it runs with chrome. Why so?

Tags: selenium, browser, testng.xml

when i run with testng.xml then IE browser opens with the message "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> <suite name="abc"> <groups> <run> <!-- include name = "HC"></include> --> <!--include name = "Reg"></include> --> <include name = "test"></include> </run> </groups> <test name="regression"> <classes> <class name="A"></class> <class name="B"></class> <class name="C"></class> </classes> </test> </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: How is your `testng.xml` defined ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="abc">
<groups>
            <run>
                <!-- include name = "HC"></include> -->
                <!--include name = "Reg"></include>  -->
                <include name = "test"></include>
            </run>
        </groups>
  <test name="regression">
    <classes>
      <class name="A"></class>
      <class name="B"></class>
      <class name="C"></class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->